# React his.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, reactjs, state

This is parent Element :

```
  changedData(){
    this.setState({
      changed: true
    }).bind(this)
  }
```

I'm passing it to the child:

```
<AboutMe  changedData={this.changedData} auth={this.props.auth} profile={profile}/>
```

The child:

```
  dataChanged(data) {
            this.props.changedData();    
      console.log("dataChanged!!")

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you bind to `this` before calling it within the function. 
You can either change your `changedData` function signature to an ES6 arrow function like this to auto bind it:

```
changedData = () => {
}
```

or you can bind it in the child component like this:

```
<AboutMe 
    changedData={this.changedData.bind(this)} 
    auth={this.props.auth} 
    profile={profile}/>
```

Comment: Or you could bind it in the constructor, which is preferable over the second suggestion (since inline binding will create a new bound function on each render).

Comment: I don't really work much with reactjs so I end up just using arrow functions for binding when I need to. Does using that for binding have any downsides compared to binding in the constructor @RobM.?

Comment: AFAIK arrow method declarations are just syntactic sugar for binding in the constructor and don't share the downsides of inline binding